# What does this test really do (Loopback TCP Network Performance)?

Tags: networking, command-line, benchmarks

I found in the phoronix test suite a [micro benchmark](http://openbenchmarking.org/innhold/1ed70546e73064b4b543782b22d45a06b045327b) called "Loopback TCP Network Performance 1.0.1", the same kind of command used [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=45513):

```
nc -d -l 9999 > /dev/null  &
time dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=10000 | nc localhost 9999
```

Does it really stress the physical network interface or only the related kernel layers?

So the question is: can we consider this command a "network" test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not test any physical network infrastructure, not even the local network interface.

What is tested it the loopback interface. It is roughly a virtual network interface that connects a computer to itself.

The test consists of sending zero bytes through the layers of the TCP/IP implementation, down to the simulated hardware device `loopback`, and back up the stack again.

The test tells you how fast the network stack implementation is, which depends mainly on how often the network data needs to be copied on the way. Only the throughput is tested, the latency is ignored.

The result should not be of much practical relevance as long as the machine is fast enough to handle the traffic. Maybe it's relevant with a 10GB network connection, or multiple 1GB connections.

On a single processor machine, I suspect that the main influence to the performance would be the process scheduling of the reader and writer - it would more like test the scheduling algorithm. But assuming both `nc` instances can use a separate CPU core, that should not be a problem.

It could be considered a network test in the sense that the network stack implementation in the kernel is an important part of the network.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it does not stress any physical devices.

Comment: Right. What would be interesting is to change it to use the physical devices; If you have two newtork interfaces, I think you can use the `-s` option of `nc` to use different local IP addresses for the `nc` instances, and connect the network cards to the same switch. (You'd need to have boths NICs in the same network, which is not the case normally)